# How can I use the regular expression in python to remove Unicode characters?

Tags: python, unicode

I've tried this code (input_str = re.sub(r'[\u06D6-\u06ED]+', '',input_str)) but it just replaces it (\u06D6 , \u06ED)

Comment: to make the question clear, can you post a sample from input text as well as the output

Comment: Every character is a Unicode character in Python, so what do you want to remove exactly?